# Do I still need multithreading or is it obsolete?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm just working myself into the boost libraries and there's one question that stucks in my head :D

Is multithreading, especially the boost one and for game  development, still used? I understand the pros of threading but I'm not sure if it's not obsolete. If not, where does it get used in game development?

RenX

Comment: Is the question about threading in general? Because threading in general is without a doubt *NOT* obsolete, nor will it be any time soon. As for boost's wrappers, that's a different matter (not saying either way, I'm not a boost user).

Comment: Even Smartphones have 4 cores, never mind a proper gaming PC. Need I say more?

Comment: The [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard has [thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) that is making Boost threading obsolete (but was probably inspired by it).

Comment: @DanielFrey to play devil's advocate, you could still do multi-core programming using nothing but `fork`. Threads aren't strictly required.

Comment: If you mean usage of boost library vs [tag:c++11] standard implementation, I'd say yes.

Comment: @Chris Right, there are several options to ruin the performance :)

Comment: Nowadays everything is in the cloud or HTML5, so multithreading and bare C++ are pretty much dead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It was near-exclusively inspired by it, actually.  Anthony Williams, the maintainer of Boost.Thread, is also at the heart of most C++11 threading papers.

Comment: @KerrekSB - in fact, I don't think we even need computers now we have the magic cloud ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're still need it. No, it is not obsolete. Moreover, multi-thread support is the one of the most progressive and integral parts of the modern game development. Almost every modern game engine has multi-thread support. Why? Because ***animation*** and the ***physics***; ***rendering*** and ***resource loading*** could performs simultaneously, and even physics itself may be [parallellized](http://www.havok.com/products/physics), this also applies to the paging. What about `boost`, [Ogre3D](http://www.krakenempire.com/blog/?p=39) uses [boost::threads](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Threading) for multi-threaded purposes (if you're an enthusiast, you should be familliar with Ogre3D, aren't you?). Unreal Engine 3 [uses the rendering thread and the game-logic thread](http://www.anandtech.com/show/1645/3), separated from the main application's thread, moreover, UE 3.5 has [Unreal Swarm](http://www.unrealengine.com/en/features/unreal_swarm/) as the job distribution system and [Gemini](http://www.unrealengine.com/en/features/rendering/) as ultra-fast HDR rendering pipeline. So yes, it has sense.